# Android studio, migrating gradle project to version 1.0

Tags: android

I want to migrate gradle project in Android Studio to version 1.0.
I have the next problem:

```
Warning:Project app: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: /home/jaume/android-studio-0.8.14/projects/Rutacomandero/app/libs/google-gson-1.7.1-release.zip
```

Comment: If you want to include any api in your project then **copy only .jar file to yourProject/app/libs** folder, here you have copied **.zip** file.

Comment: you may have forgotten `repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}` see my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/28898586/1815624

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "google-gson-1.7.1-release.zip" is just the gson dependency, then include it in your `dependencies` section of your build.gradle file, like so:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1'
```

You should be depending on jar files, not zips, and in the case of gson, grab it from central rather than keeping a copy in libs.

Also, 1.7.1 is old, since you're upgrading anyway, try 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and I was able to resolve it by adding

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

so use:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5' 
}
```

I exampled version 2.5 but you should check for updates. see https://github.com/google/gson/releases

My answer was found at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/getting-started-with-google-gson.html